# How to split an array in liquid templates?

Tags: spotify, liquid

I have an array that looks like this.

```
my_array = [
    {'first': 'foo'},
    {'second': 'bar'},
    {'third': 'baz'},
    {'fourth': 'qux'}
]
```

I'm trying to render the first two items using liquid templating. How do I achieve this WITHOUT using the index ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [limit tag](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/):

```
{% for thing in my_array limit:2 %}
   <p>{{thing.whatever}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```